# to give a specific string value as default field value

Tags: java

In the below code, it should take alarm default value as "Alarm_002", but i am not getting with the below code.Can any one please suggest me

```
for (Site site : siteList) {
            dto = new SiteDto();
            dto.setResultCode(ResultMessage.SUCCESS.code().toString());
            dto.setResultMessage(ResultMessage.SUCCESS.message());

            dto.setSiteCode(site.getCode());
            char[] Alarm_002 = null;
            dto.setAreaName(String.copyValueOf(Alarm_002));
            dto.setAlarmMsgType(site.getAlarmMsgType());
            dto.setDailyMsgType(site.getDailyMsgType());
            dto.setLogMsgType(site.getLogMsgType());`enter code here`
            dto.setCircleCode(site.getCircle().getCode());
            if (site.getSiteLocation() != null) {
                dto.setLocationDetails(new LocationDetailsDto(site.getSiteLocation().getLatitude(), site.getSiteLocation().getLongitude()));
            }
            dto.setOperatorCode(site.getOperator().getCode());
            dto.setSwVersion(site.getSwVersion());
            siteListDto.add(dto);
            siteRequest.getSiteCodeList().remove(site.getCode());
        }
```

Comment: not getting any exception

Comment: char[] Alarm_002 = {'A','l','a','r','m','_','0','0','2'}; use this

Answer (score 0):

Actually, `String.copyValueOf(Alarm_002)` piece of code will give `NullPointerException`. So initialize the char array properly.

```
      char[] Alarm_002 = null;  
      dto.setAreaName(String.copyValueOf(Alarm_002));
```

Internally looking, it calls `value.length`, where value is nothing but your array, which is null in your case.

Sample

```
 public static void main(String[] args) {
        char[] Alarm_002 = null;
        System.out.println(String.copyValueOf(Alarm_002));
    }
```

**output**

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at java.lang.String.copyValueOf(String.java:2892)'
```

**Fixed code**

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        char[] Alarm_002 = { 'A', 'l', 'a', 'r', 'm', '_', '0', '0', '2' };
        System.out.println(String.copyValueOf(Alarm_002));
    }
```

**output**

```
Alarm_002
```